# make the whole body unclickable except one div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a html page with a button that shows and hides a div (which is initially hidden) on click.
when visible, i want only that div to be clickable not any other elements.
Here's the code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mybtn').click(function() {
  //to make the '.frontdiv' visible
    $(".frontdiv").toggle( );
    $('*').off("click")
    $('.frontdiv').on("click")
  });
  //by pressing the 'x' button i want the '.frontdiv' to hide again and make the whole body clickable again
  $('.x').click(function() {
    $(".frontdiv").toggle();
  });  
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.backdiv {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.frontdiv {
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
}

#mybtn {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.x {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 92%;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="backdiv">
    <div class="frontdiv"><button class="x"> x </button></div>
    <button id="mybtn">CLICK</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

by running the  snippet it must've been clear what i'm trying to achieve here, so please help me
**Also**: how can i make the '.frontdiv' disappear when i click anywhere outside that div ?

Answer (score 0):

I added an extra div called `<div class="popup">`. This div will cover the whole screen and will center your `<div class="frontdiv">` div. The X to toggle the popup will work now, since we are toggling the `<div class="popup">` div.

Please check the code snippet for the result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mybtn').click(function() {
    $(".popup").toggle();
  });
  $('.x').click(function() {
    $(".popup").toggle();
  });  
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.backdiv {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.popup{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.frontdiv {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
}

#mybtn {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.x {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 92%;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="backdiv">
    <button id="mybtn">CLICK</button>
  </div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="frontdiv">
      <button class="x"> x </button>    
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```